# Defining an optional-argument extern for a function with a required nullable int argument

Tags: haxe

Let's suppose that you have an extern function that takes a `Null<Int>` argument.
The argument is required in target API, but you want it to default to 0 when called from Haxe. That is,

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        Ext.func();
        Ext.func(1);
        Ext.func(null);
    }
}
extern class Ext { ... definition for func }
```

should produce

```
Ext.func(0);
Ext.func(1);
Ext.func(null);
```

accordingly.

This proves strangely problematic, let's go over my considerations so far:

### The obvious approach

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        Ext.func();
        Ext.func(0);
        Ext.func(null);
    }
}
extern class Ext {
    static function func(v:Null<Int> = 0):Void;
}
```

Produces

```
Ext.func(); // (note the omitted parameter)
Ext.func(0);
Ext.func(null);
```

and thus your generated code doesn't compile.

### Inline wrapper

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        Ext.func();
        Ext.func(1);
        Ext.func(null);
    }
}
extern class Ext {
    static inline function func(v:Null<Int> = 0):Void {
        realFunc(v);
    }
    @:native("func") private static function realFunc(v:Null<Int>):Void;
}
```

Produces

```
Ext.func(0);
Ext.func(1);
Ext.func(0); // (note the null turning into 0)
```

and thus your code doesn't work as intended.

### Macros

[As an old saying goes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQhuB.png), any omission in Haxe can be corrected with a sufficiently sophisticated macro. This proves true once again, but at what price?

Test.hx:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        Ext.func();
        Ext.func(1);
        Ext.func(null);
    }
}
```

RealExt.hx:

```
@:native("Ext") extern class RealExt {
    static function func(v:Null<Int>):Void;
}
```

Ext.hx:

```
import haxe.macro.Expr;
class Ext {
    public static macro function func(args:Array<Expr>):Expr {
        if (args.length > 1) throw "Too many arguments!";
        var v = args[0];
        if (v == null) v = macro 0;
        return macro RealExt.func($v);
    }
}
```

So we can't put a macro into an extern class, therefore a proxy class is needed (if you wanted this in an utility class, I guess you now got redundancy... unless you want to write a macro that iterates over class fields and builds a proxy class?), and you can't just have an optional ?expr argument (or it'll turn into a EConst(CIdent(null))), so there's this small monstrosity. But it works, yes

```
Ext.func(0);
Ext.func(1);
Ext.func(null);
```

### Admitting your defeat

Maybe things are never as easy as we want them to be.

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        Ext.func();
        Ext.funcExt(1);
        Ext.funcExt(null);
    }
}
extern class Ext {
    static inline function func():Void {
        funcExt(0);
    }
    @:native("func") static function funcExt(v:Null<Int>):Void;
}
```

Obviously, this works,

```
Ext.func(0);
Ext.func(1);
Ext.func(null);
```

but doesn't look very clean.

### Not admitting your defeat

I don't know if this is better or worse

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        Ext.func();
        Ext.func(1);
        Ext.funcWithNull();
    }
}
extern class Ext {
    static inline function func(v:Null<Int> = 0):Void {
        funcExt(v);
    }
    static inline function funcWithNull():Void {
        funcExt(null);
    }
    @:native("func") private static function funcExt(v:Null<Int>):Void;
}
```

Obviously this only works if you know that you're going to call it with `null` and also doesn't work if there's more than one such argument.

### Using a magic value to indicate that you wanted a null

This sounds like asking for trouble, maybe let's not

---

Perhaps there's a better way to do this?